# iron ajax Polymer body empty on server side

Tags: javascript, ajax, polymer

I am new to Polymer, Javascript and Ajax so I have some difficulties to achieve what I want.

I would like to have a client side that send 2 data (number and string) to the server side in order to store it into a mysql database.

I managed to do almost everything except the data transmission with an Ajax connection. I can connect both sides but for some reason the body received is empty. Here is my code: 
`

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-slider/paper-slider.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-autogrow-textarea/iron-autogrow-textarea.html">

<dom-module id="icon-toggle-demo">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        font-family: sans-serif;
      };
    </style>


<h3>Rating</h3>

    <paper-slider id="ratings" pin snaps min="1" pin snaps max="4" max-markers="4" step="1" value="5"></paper-slider>

    <h3>Commentaire</h3>
    <iron-autogrow-textarea id="comment" label="Commentaire"></iron-autogrow-textarea>

    <!-- curly brackets ({{}}} allow two-way binding --> 
    <button on-click="f">Soumettre</button>
    <p id="noteR">[[text]]</p>
    <p id="commentR">[[text2]]</p>

<iron-ajax 
id="request" 
url="/request" 
method="POST" 
on-response="_refresh"
body: {note: 6, comment: "TUT"}>
</iron-ajax>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: "icon-toggle-demo",
      properties: {
        text: {value: ""},
        text2: {value: ""}
      },
      f: function() {
        var body = {"note": this.querySelector("#ratings").value,
        "comment": this.querySelector("#comment").value
        };

        this.$.request.body = body;
        console.log(this.$.request.body);
        this.$.request.generateRequest();
        this.set("text","Vous avez mis une note de: "+document.getElementById("ratings").value);
        this.set("text2",document.getElementById("comment").value); 
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

`

This was from the client side, console.log does give me the right object with right variables and the right values, so everything seems good.

Now the server side:

```
    var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.sendFile("C:/Users/combesb/Desktop/ServeurPoly/index.html");
});

//Javascript insert sql request
router.post('/request', function(req, res, next){

console.log(req.body);
console.log(req.body.comment);

});
```

The first console.log gives me {}, so that means the object is empty, the second one prints undefined.

I don't really know where the issues is and how to fix it.

Thank you a lot for taking the time to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `application/json` as the `content-type`.

#### Example:

```
<iron-ajax method="POST" url="foo.com" content-type="application/json> </iron-ajax>
```